# JSF 2.0 Displaying all validation messages of multiple validators

Tags: validation, jsf

I have an `h:inputText` element with more than one validators, eg.:

```
<h:inputText id="myId" value="#{some.value}">
    <f:validator validatorId="validatorOne/>
    <f:validator validatorId="validatorTwo/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="myId"/>
```

Now if I implement my validators to throw a `ValidatorException`, the second validator won't run, even if it would fail as well.

But I'd like both validators to run and to diplay both error messages in case both validations fail.

I've already tried not to throw `ValidatorException` like this:

```
    facesContext.addMessage(uiComponent.getClientId(), facesMessage);
    ((UIInput)uiComponent).setValid(false);
```

But the `h:message` won't display both of the error messages, although I can see them if I use `h:messages`.

How is it possible to display all validation error messages?

Comment: To see all of them you would use `h:messages` but you already know this.  I am fairly certain that `h:message` will only ever display one validation message.  If this is not good enough you may need to create a custom component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way how JSF validators are specified to work. The validators are fired in the order they're declared on the component and if one of them fails, then the remnant won't be fired.

If using `<h:messages>` is really not an option for some unclear reason (perhaps you weren't aware about its `for` attribute which works the same way?), then your best bet is creating another validator which in turn delegates to the both validators and merges the caught validator exceptions into one.

Comment: I tried to use this as you described but I was actually using primefaces' `<p:messages>` which does not work the same way as `<h:messages>` (indeed I'm using this for the first time). If I set the `for` attribute in the former one, it does not show any messages, while the latter one is showing the correct results. Perhaps a bug in primefaces? Still my fault for not testing this for the `h` namespace.

Comment: Report it to PrimeFaces. In future JSF questions please talk about the real code instead of obfuscating/simplifying it to the standard component set.